# Updating table rows from different table data not working

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress

I have two tables in my database. One called `wp_tickets` and another one called `wp_tickets_regenerated`.

I'm trying to update some of the data in the `wp_tickets_regenerated` table from the `wp_tickets` table if the `lottery_id` matches so i end up with a new table with different ticket_number generated for each order placed for that product.

The code I have so far is throwing up an error:

```
 WordPress database error You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM wp_tickets
        WHERE lottery_id = wp_tickets.lottery_id' at line 6 for query UPDATE wp_tickets_regenerated
```

Can anyone help please?

**wp_tickets table**

```
+---------+-----------+-----------+---------------+----------+------------+
| user_id | full_name | answer_id | ticket_number | order_id | lottery_id |
+---------+-----------+-----------+---------------+----------+------------+
| 0       | test      | 1         | 3             | 791      | 790        |
+---------+-----------+-----------+---------------+----------+------------+
| 0       | test      | 1         | 5             | 791      | 790        |
+---------+-----------+-----------+---------------+----------+------------+
| 0       | test      | 1         | 10            | 791      | 790        |
+---------+-----------+-----------+---------------+----------+------------+
```

**wp_tickets_regenerated**

```
   +---------+-----------+-----------+---------------+----------+------------+
    | user_id | full_name | answer_id | ticket_number | order_id | lottery_id |
    +---------+-----------+-----------+---------------+----------+------------+
    |         |           |           | 1             |          | 790        |
    +---------+-----------+-----------+---------------+----------+------------+
    |         |           |           | 2             |          | 790        |
    +---------+-----------+-----------+---------------+----------+------------+
    |         |           |           | 3             |          | 790        |
    +---------+-----------+-----------+---------------+----------+------------+
```

What i have so far is:

```
 $wpdb->query(
       'UPDATE wp_tickets_regenerated
        SET user_id = wp_tickets.user_id,
            full_name = wp_tickets.full_name,
            answer_id = wp_tickets.answer_id,
            order_id = wp_tickets.order_id
        FROM wp_tickets
        WHERE lottery_id = wp_tickets.lottery_id'
  );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a inner join table `wp_tickets` for update

Try this

```
UPDATE wp_tickets_regenerated
INNER JOIN wp_tickets ON wp_tickets_regenerated.lottery_id = wp_tickets.lottery_id
SET wp_tickets_regenerated.user_id = wp_tickets .user_id,
    wp_tickets_regenerated.full_name = wp_tickets .full_name,
    wp_tickets_regenerated.answer_id = wp_tickets .answer_id,
    wp_tickets_regenerated.order_id = wp_tickets .order_id
WHERE wp_tickets_regenerated.lottery_id = wp_tickets.lottery_id'
```

**Hope this will help you**

Answer (score 0):

Could be you need  a inner join for update

```
    UPDATE wp_tickets_regenerated a 
    INNER JOIN wp_tickets b a.lottery_id = b.lottery_id
    SET a.user_id = b.user_id,
        a.full_name = b.full_name,
        a.answer_id = b.answer_id,
        a.order_id = b.order_id
```

(from in update ...is not used)